# What does ** mean in Phing?

Tags: filter, phing

The Phing User's Guide uses the following description of the ** file filter:

"Two asterisks (**) may include above the "border" of the directory separator."

I'm having a hard time deciphering what this really means. Can somebody please translate this into English?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`**` matches any character while `*` matches anything except for a directory separator.

For example, `/path/**` will match either of these:

- /path/file
- /path/to/some/file
- /path/to/some/other/file

However, `/path/*` will only match the first one.

Comment: Here's an example from the Phing User Guide:

"**/*.ent.xml fits to all files that end with ent.xml in all subdirectories of the directory specified with the dir attribute of the <fileset> tag. However, it will not include any files that are directly in the base directory of the file set."

This one was confounding me, but now I think I get it. The reason it doesn't match any files in the base directory has nothing to do with the nature of ** itself, but is because the filter starts with **/, which I take it to mean that the files must be in a subdirectory.  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, the path `filename.ent.xml` (a file in the base directory) does not match the pattern `**/*.ent.xml` since it doesn't contain any `/` character.

Comment: Thank you. The description of ** from the user guide is really bad. Your description makes more sense.